# Regex to remove prefix of a pattern (R)

Tags: java, r, regex

I have two strings, `S` and `T`. How do I use regex to remove copies of prefixes of `T` from the end of `S`?

More specifically, `S` consists of some characters followed by some copies of `T`, where the last one may be truncated. For instance, say `T` is `abcdef` and `S` is `asdjb|ak.fvajfabcdefabcdefabcdefabc` -- then what I would like to get is `asdjb|ak.fvajf`.

Additionally, `S` and `T` may contain characters with special meaning to regex engines, such as `.[]*+()\`. I'm working in R, but a solution in Java would be fine too.

Comment: why wasn't "a" removed since it was also a prefix

Comment: Do you mean `T` is `abcde`? The `f` is a typo right?

Comment: @Sweeper I've added the `f` in too

Comment: @marvel308 I'd like to only remove prefixes of `T` from the *end* of `S`, and stop once there aren't any left

Comment: Just as a note: if it's at the end it's a suffix, not a prefix :).

Comment: why you don't use `replace` like `s.replace(t, "")` ?

Comment: @RuiBarradas it's at the end of `S`, but it's a prefix of `T`

Comment: @YCF_L I believe that Java method will only remove complete copies of `T` from `S` -- so the final output will be `asdjb|ak.fvajfabc` instead of `asdjb|ak.fvajf`

Comment: I think you need a regex like `[abcdef]+$` ;).

Comment: Ok, thanks for making it more clear. So you want to remove entire `T` or just a prefix of `T` from `S`, not the entire string. Got it.

Comment: @shA.t unfortunately that will remove too much, ending up with `asdjb|ak.fvaj`

Comment: Try `S.replaceAll("(a|ab|abc|abcd|abcde|abcdef)+$", "")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this does it. But it's really long.

```
S <- "asdjb|ak.fvajfabcdefabcdefabcdefabc"
T <- "abcdef"
want <- "asdjb|ak.fvajf"

sp <- strsplit(T, "")[[1]]
pat <- sapply(seq_along(sp), function(i){
                paste(sp[seq_len(i)], collapse = "")
            })
pat <- paste0("(", paste(pat, collapse = "|"), ")*$")

result <- gsub(pat, "", S)
identical(result, want)
[1] TRUE
```

If you want to process several vectors, rewrite the above as a function and then use `sapply`. (Or `lapply`.)

```
repl <- function(x, prefix){
    sp <- strsplit(prefix, "")[[1]]
    pat <- sapply(seq_along(sp), function(i){
                paste(sp[seq_len(i)], collapse = "")
            })
    pat <- paste0("(", paste(pat, collapse = "|"), ")*$")
    result <- gsub(pat, "", x)
    result
}

where <- rep(S, 10)
pref <- rep(T, 10)

sapply(seq_along(where), function(i) repl(where[[i]], pref[[i]]))
```

Comment: Thanks! For additional imaginary Internet points, suppose that `S` and `T` are vectors with the same numbers of elements. How would one vectorise the above code?

Comment: @LiamBaker I'll edit my code with a possible answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this

```
final String regex = "a(b|(bc|(bcd|(bcde|bcdef))))?$";
String string = "asdjb|ak.fvajfabcdefabcdefabcdefabc";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
int length = 0;
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    length += matcher.group(0).length();
    matcher = pattern.matcher(string.substring(0, string.length()- length));
}
System.out.println(string.substring(0, string.length()- length));
```

[demo](http://ideone.com/3ww8ab)

> Output : asdjb|ak.fvajf